# Unwanted concatenation of multiple #+TITLE and #+AUTHOR when using #+INCLUDE

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have 2 documents, one of which I'd like to include in the other. The first is an assignment sheet, and the second the rubric I'm going to use to grade the assignment. I want to `#+INCLUDE` the rubric with the assignment so I can discuss it with the class when I assign it, but I have it as a separate file so I can fill out a copy for each student's paper when I'm grading them.

The rubric and assignment sheet both have `#+TITLE` and `#+AUTHOR` fields, viz:

ASSIGNMENT SHEET:

```
#+OPTIONS: date:nil toc:nil num:nil
#+TITLE: Assignment Sheet
#+AUTHOR: me

* heading
#+INCLUDE: "rubric.org"
```

RUBRIC:

```
#+TITLE: rubric
#+AUTHOR: me

* content
  some content
```

When I export `assignment-sheet.org` with `C-c C-e l o` the result has both titles and both authors concatenated:

[image]

I wish the included file's redundant `#+TITLE` and `#+AUTHOR` could be subordinated to the those of the main file. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll have a try.

To exclude first two lines of "rubric.org".
include lines from 3 to end of file.

```
#+OPTIONS: date:nil toc:nil num:nil
#+TITLE: Assignment Sheet
#+AUTHOR: me

* heading
#+INCLUDE: "rubric.org" :lines "3-"
```

- [11.4 Include files](http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html)

Comment: You're welcome! I'm not an expert, there must to be a more sophisticated solution.